# What reference I need to use NHibernate QueryOver?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, queryover

I can't find out what namespace reference is needed to use NHibernate's QueryOver?

How do you find out this type of things anyway? Is there any searchable documentation where I "should have looked"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a reference to `NHibernate` (it's a method of `ISession`).  Do note, though, that it's only available starting in NH 3.0.

```
using NHibernate;
```

More [**here**](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx).

Comment: Ah.. I thought I had 3.0, but didn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
using NHibernate;
```

is the reference that you need to add..

Apart from this I would suggest you try out this amazing tool call Resharper. If you start using it you will never ever work without it believe me.. its the best tool i have used in a year.
try the trial version and then think about getting a licence.
here is the link [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/index.html)

Enjoy..